# How to avoid writing identical methods for the sam struct nested in multiple types in GO?

Tags: go

I have 2 structs, `ModelA` and `ModelB`, that share an embedded struct `BaseModel`:

```
type BaseModel struct {
    Id     int
    Val    string
}
type ModelA struct {
    BaseModel
    ValA   string
}
type ModelB struct {
    BaseModel
    ValB   string
    ValBB   string
}
```

The interface `Model` has 2 purposes:

1. Allow functions to receive `ModelA` and `ModelB` as `Model`.
2. Define a list of getters/setters for the fields of `BaseModel` embedded in `ModelA` and `ModelB`.

```
type Model interface {
    ID() int
    SetId(int)

    Val() string
    SetVal(string)
}
```

In order for `ModelA` and `ModelB` to implement the `Model` interface, I need to implement all of `Model` methods for each of the 2 types.

This implementation does the job but I need to implement 2x2x2 methods:

- 2 concrete structs `ModelA` and `ModelB`
- 2 fields in the shared nested-struct `BaseModel`
- 1 setter and 1 getter method per `BaseModel` field

Is there a way to get similar functionality without writing identical methods for multiple types?

Comment: BaseModel can implement ID() and SetID(), and then you're left with just 2x2 which is fine since you have two different structs whose methods do two different things.

Comment: @mkopriva if `ID()` and `SetID()` are defined on `BaseModel`, I will need to define a `BaseModel() BaseModel` method in the `Model` interface and implement it for the 2 types. This so I can run `.BaseModel().ID()` and `.BaseModel().SetID()` on variables of type `Model`.
Did I understand your suggestion correctly?

Comment: Methods of an embedded type are promoted to the embedding type. They become part of the method set and contribute to implementing interfaces. See https://gobyexample.com/embedding (especially the last paragraph).